# React-Native Image Loading from Shorten URL Not Working

Tags: image, api, react-native, url-shortener

I'm Rendering the `<Image>` Component Having The Remote server URL for Image as Given Below,

```
<Image source={{ uri: 'bit.ly/2RkIi9w' }} style={{ width:100 , height:100}} />
```

But it's not Working as aspected. the original url which is shortened is using the protocol `https://`.

I have tried by giving it plain url and it's working perfectly fine. but not with the shortened url.

```
<Image source={{ uri: 'https://d1w7fb2mkkr3kw.cloudfront.net/assets/images/book/lrg/9780/1363/9780136350385.jpg' }} style={{ width:100 , height:100}} />
```

why it's happening? is the url redirect making error in react-native? if there is any solution, tell me.

Answer (score 2):

It's Simple, You only need to add the protocol before the link, as

```
<Image source={{ uri: 'https://'+your_link }} style={{ width:100 , height:100}} />
```

Will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the protocol `https` before the link:

```
<Image source={{ uri: 'https://bit.ly/<path>' }} style={{ width:100 , height:100}} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, To expand your shortened URL.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-shortener

```
// first argument should shortened url
expand('https://goo.gl/').then(response => {
  console.log(response.id);
  console.log(response.longUrl);
});
```